# Custom Alert View fails to change orientation in iOS 7.1 simulator

Tags: objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation, ios7.1

I have created a custom alert view and I am adding it to to the UIWindow. The problem is that when I change the orientation of the iOS 7.1 simulator, the orientation of the alert view does not change. The orientation changes properly while working on iOS 8 simulator.
Here is where I am adding it to the UIWindow:

```
-(void)show
{
    UIWindow *pWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    [pWindow addSubview:self];
    self.frame = pWindow.bounds;
}
```

The custom alert view gets loaded from a view controller class, when any  cell of its table view gets tapped:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.customAlert) {

        self.customAlert = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomAlertViewWIthGesture copy"
                                                          owner:self
                                                        options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    self.customAlert.delegate = self;

    self.customAlert.staticText = @"All 100 entities selected";
    self.customAlert.actionableText = @"Select all from server";

    [self.customAlert show];

}
```

[image: The Landscape view of the alert]

Answer (score 1):

Subview of `UIWindow` doesn't support rotation.`UIViewController` class support rotation. This isn't problem actually. People rotating subviews of window manually since prior version of iOS. You must show your alert view on `UIViewController` instead of `UIWindow`. If you want `UIWindow` then implement manual rotation methods.

Comment: As far as I know, the interface orientation callbacks are implemented in the View controller only, right? And that shall include redefining the frame size etc. I am using auto layout constraints for the view. So managing the frame size on interface orientation doesn't seem to be a great idea to me.

Comment: As far as i know you have no choice managing frame sizes. In such condition i always prefer to add subview on rootviewcontroller so it reduced lots of headache.

Comment: Yup.. :) I have posted an answer. For system versions less than iOS 8.0, the alert view gets added to the first subview of the window, which is the view controller essentially. For iOS 8 and above, the alert view gets added to the window as before.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
UIWindow *pWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 8.0) {


        [[[pWindow subviews] firstObject] addSubview:self];

    }
    else {

        [pWindow addSubview:self];
    }
```

Works fine. Please do let know if there are any technical issues with this solution.